# Where did the words "white-collar" and "blue-collar" come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms, colors

I can kinda see the "white-collar" image, with formal dress shirts, but "blue-collar" is not intuitive to me, and Dictionary.com and Etymonline are not helpful as to the reason for the color choice.  Does anyone know the reason for the color blue in "blue-collar"?

Comment: Actually the reference is to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Boilersuit2.jpg) kind of clothing. You can find more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-collar_worker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Blue collar" is a reference to the overalls worn by workers in jobs which require working with tools.

The [overalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overalls) protect their clothing.

Comment: But overalls don't have collars.

Comment: *Some overall do*. Look at the 'boilersuit' coversalls in the Wikipedia article.